# Search for bookmarks from Chrome's URL search bar using self-hosted application's API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I recently created and self-hosted a bookmarks management application.

My question is, can I search for the bookmark from Chrome directly inside the URL search bar through API to my application? I tried to search the documentation and their given examples and I can not find something usable.

Please point me out if I missed something.

Thank you